# multiple bars with react-native-chart-kit <BarChart />

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-native-chart-kit

This is what i tried: and it doesn't work
i need to make multiple bars like so:
[multiple bars chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFHYY.png)

```
<BarChart
        style={{ marginVertical: 8, borderRadius: 8 }}
        data={{
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [20, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43],
            },
            {
              data: [70, 25, 98, 40, 19, 23],
            },
          ],
        }}
        width={hValues.screenWidth}
        height={220}
        yAxisLabel="$"
        chartConfig={chartConfig}
        verticalLabelRotation={30}
      />
```